# Does a Foucault pendulum move quicker above than below of the apparatus?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, time-dilation, coriolis-effect

Because of gravity on earth, a time period is slower at low altitude than at high altitude.

Does a Foucault pendulum move quicker above than below of the apparatus because of gravitational time dilation?

Answer (score 2):

The gravitational time dilation in Schwarzschild (static spherical mass) implies
$\Delta t = (1 - 2M/r)^{-1/2} \Delta \tau$
where:
$c = G = 1$ natural units
$M$ = black hole mass
$\tau$ proper time of a stationary observer at distance $r$
$r \gt 2M = r_s$ Schwarzschild radius
$t$ coordinate time of an observer at infinity
At infinity the time is running faster.

If we consider two stationary observers at distances $r_1$ and $r_2$ with $r_2 \gt r_1$, we have
$\Delta \tau_2 = (1 - 2M/r_1)^{-1/2} / (1 - 2M/r_2)^{-1/2} \Delta \tau_1$
A clock of a stationary observer farther from the mass ticks faster than a clock closer.

The answer to the question is yes, a Foucault pendulum moves quicker above than below the apparatus, because of the gravitational time dilation.